# VSE: One video overlays another - bottom one plays as expected, top one does not

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I'm trying to overlay a screen recording of my phone on another video. Both videos are 1920x1080 and 50fps. It renders as expected, with the screen recording taking up a third of the image on the left and the other video playing on the back. My problem is with seeking in the VSE: jumping to a frame, the bottom video jumps to the correct frame, whereas the top video will always start from its first frame.

Why is this?

UPDATE: The video of my phone's screen was taken with AZ Screen Recorder. I'd set it to 50 FPS, but VLC tells me the framerate is something else. I was able to work smoothly with these videos using DaVinci Resolve, where I had to set the phone video's frame rate to 200.

Top video settings:

[image: Top video settings]

Transform settings:

[image: Transform settings]

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/49219/2843

Comment: That answer is a muddled mess. The issue is a combination of discontinuous frame rates and I/P/B frames.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure your footages are conformed to identical frame rates. You will, for example, almost never find any North American device that will record at a flat 24, 50, 60, etc. and the *actual* value will be 24000/1001, 50000/1001, 60000/1001 etc. Assert that your framerates are identical, if they are not, you will need to conform them to identical rates, with the below caveat.
2. Conform to a motion picture codec that uses only I frames, which represent a whole frame. The FFMPEG library behind the scenes will be calculating offsets into the overall time stamps, and this will yield wonky results when you are dealing with compressed codecs leaning heavily on groups of pictures, or *GOP*s. The only way to avoid this, and have your cuts match perfectly 1:1 is to enforce codecs that avoid those I and P frames.

Bluntly, for this sort of an application, Blender is a poor tool, as still image formats are going to be vastly more reliable. In the context of your particular project, still image formats seem outside the scope.

See [Audio/Video out of sync in rendered video, but not in VSE](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31471/audio-video-out-of-sync-in-rendered-video-but-not-in-vse) for more information.